# I don't understand why I'm getting the CS8347 error while trying to make an extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ref, out

I was trying to create a simple extension method wrapper around [CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault?view=net-6.0) and I ran into a problem I don't quite understand.

This code works:

```
public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, out bool exists)
    where TKey : notnull
{
    return ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out exists);
}
```

If I try not to pass the `out bool exists` variable outside of the method by discarding it or by just storing it in a local variable, it doesn't work:

```
public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    where TKey : notnull
{
    return ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out _);
    // Error: Cannot use a result of CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(..) in this context because
    // it may expose variables referenced by parameter 'exists' outside of their declaration scope
}
```

To me this error sounds a lot like something I should get when trying to return a reference to a local variable. I just don't get why I'm getting the error by **simply not using / passing out** the boolean I received, and how could that omission possibly reference anything out of scope.

Also, the error disappears when I use a dummy variable outside of the scope of the method, but I'd rather not do that:

```
private static bool dummy;
public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    where TKey : notnull
{
    return ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out dummy);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps include the Error itself in your question? From [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/43e4950a65961e2194e4ce082d64bc31): _CS8347 -- Cannot use a result of '{0}' in this context because it may expose variables referenced by parameter '{1}' outside of their declaration scope_

Comment: @RichardDeeming I'm writing this in a .Net 6 console application in VS2022.

Comment: @AstridE. I actually did include the error. It is in the middle code snippet.

Comment: @RichardDeeming You misunderstand. The top code snippet works, it is the middle one that doesn't work. Look at [this (edited) demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EwnuhJ)

Comment: @Petrusion Oh, my bad! It definitely is included where you say it is.

Comment: @Petrusion OK, that makes sense. As far as the compiler is concerned, the value returned *could be* a reference to the `out` parameter, which is a local variable in the discard case. Technically, the compiler *could* chose to allow this if `TValue` had constrains which meant it couldn't possibly be `bool`; but that could be somewhat confusing, and possibly difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RichardDeeming noted in comment: the returned reference could be a reference to the `out` parameter, which is a local variable in the discard case.

This issue is resolved by C#11 [Low-level struct improvements # Change the behavior of out parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements#change-the-behavior-of-out-parameters)

> the language will change the default *ref-safe-to-escape* value for `out`
> parameters to be *current method*. Effectively `out` parameters are
> implicitly `scoped out` going forward.
> ......
> The language will also no longer consider arguments passed to an `out`
> parameter to be returnable.

---

Note: if you using `<LangVersion>` 11 or higher with pre `net7` TFM, compiler will use those new rules, but reference assembly would still be annotated as `RefSafetyRules(10 /*or less*/)` so `out` var defined in `GetValueRefOrAddDefault` would still not be treated as `scoped`.
You can define `UnscopedRefAttribute` and annotate your wrapper `out` var with it to resolve this issue.

```cs
namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public sealed class UnscopedRefAttribute : Attribute {}
}

public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey, TValue>(
  this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key,
  [UnscopedRef] out bool exists)
  { ... }
```